# Gravity Forms Add descriptions to radio buttons

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to add an HTML element to each radio button, just after each  tag without having to jam all the html into the label field.

So where a radio button renders as

```
<li class='gchoice_10_5_0'>
    <input name='input_5' type='radio' value='Item 1|10'  id='choice_10_5_0' tabindex='1' />
    <label for='choice_10_5_0' id='label_10_5_0'>First Choice</label>
</li>
```

I am trying to generate

```
<li class='gchoice_10_5_0'>
    <input name='input_5' type='radio' value='Item 1|10'  id='choice_10_5_0' tabindex='1' />
    <label for='choice_10_5_0' id='label_10_5_0'>First Choice</label>
    <div>New html here</div>
</li>
```

I can do this with jQuery but need to use dynamically generated id's and custom fields:

```
var html1 = "";
html += '<ul class="symptom column severe">';
html += '<li>blah blah blah</li>';
html += '<li>blah blah blah</li>';
html += '<li>blah blah blah</li>';
html += '<li>blah blah blah</li>';
html += '</ul>';
$( html ).appendTo( ".gchoice_1_2_3" );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to modify the form output by using the `gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render` filter as described in the [Gravity Forms documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render/#4-add-css-class-to-multiselect-choice)

Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render_4', function ( $choice_markup, $choice, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'radio' && rgar( $choice, 'text' ) == 'Option 1' ) {
        $description = '<div>New html here</div>';
        return str_replace( "</label>", "</label>$description", $choice_markup );
    }

    return $choice_markup;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Extending for multiple radio buttons and Advanced Custom Fields:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_choice_markup_pre_render_4', function ( $choice_markup, $choice, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'radio' ) :

        switch ( rgar( $choice, 'text' ) ) {
            case "Option 1":
                $description = get_field('option_1');
                break;
            case "Option 2":
                $description = get_field('option_2');
                break;
            case "Option 3":
                $description = get_field('option_3');
                break;
        }

    endif;

    return str_replace( "</label>", "</label>$description", $choice_markup );

}, 10, 4 );
```